# Forum Funding System donations earmarked for projects that are never completed

Tags: multisig, forum-funding-system

What happens to Monero raised by the Forum Funding System for projects that are never completed?

Are donations returned to donors (if their identity is known)?

What happens to donations made by anonymous donors?

Once multisig integration of Monero is compete will the Forum Funding System take advantage of it to help decentralize some control of donation disbursements?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- Monero related projects that are not finished or do not hit certain milestones will have the donated XMR/BTC/USD used for other Monero related projects.
- Donations are non-refundable and go into a development pool to be used on Monero projects. (This also answers what happens to donations if they are made by anonymous donors).
- As for multisig and the forum funding system, the Monero core team hasn't explored the topic yet and will wait until multisig is available to use before they think of applying it to the forum funding system.